# php for tax calculate

Tags: magento-1.9, php

i try to calculate tax for export.Every price in magento admin had already inserted with tax include. So the only sollution i can think is to calculate it at success page.

With tax 24% i try to calculate it by

```
<?php $tax = ($totalprice->getSubtotal() /1.24)*0.24; ?>
```

is it a syntax error?

Any other way to auto calculate magento the prices and tax?